# R - How to build a nested list without duplicated sub-list declaration?

Tags: r, list, nested, code-duplication

Would there be a standard approach to **building nested lists** in which the sub-lists contain the same structure, to **remove duplication** ?

Dummy example structure:

- a "top" list (wordsList), containing one sub-list (languageType)
- this sub-list contains "sub-sub lists" (french, english, falty), which each contain another list with the same structure:
  sentenceType, with each elems a sub-list (leBien, leMal)

How to build such a structure without duplication ? (so to assign to elem of languageType the list sentenceType)

Example expected output:

```
wordsList <- list(
  languageType = list(
    french = list(
      sentenceType = list(
        leBien = c("Bien", "le", "bonjour", "messieurs", "dames"),
        leMal = c("Mal", "la", "bonsoir", "mesdames", "sieurs")
      )
    ),
    english = list(
      sentenceType = list(
        leBien = c("Well", "hello", "my", "good", "sire", "or", "madame"),
        leMal = c("Bad", "goodbye", "your", "bad", "madame", "and", "sire")
      )
    ),
    falty = list(
      sentenceType = list(
        leBien = c(1:10),
        leMal = list("this", "is", 0, 5, "not correct !")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

```
str(wordsList)
List of 1
 $ languageType:List of 3
  ..$ french :List of 1
  .. ..$ sentenceType:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ leBien: chr [1:5] "Bien" "le" "bonjour" "messieurs" ...
  .. .. ..$ leMal : chr [1:5] "Mal" "la" "bonsoir" "mesdames" ...
  ..$ english:List of 1
  .. ..$ sentenceType:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ leBien: chr [1:7] "Well" "hello" "my" "good" ...
  .. .. ..$ leMal : chr [1:7] "Bad" "goodbye" "your" "bad" ...
  ..$ falty  :List of 1
  .. ..$ sentenceType:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ leBien: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  .. .. ..$ leMal :List of 5
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "this"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "is"
  .. .. .. ..$ : num 0
  .. .. .. ..$ : num 5
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "not correct !"
```

Comment: could you post expected result?

Comment: I added the str output of the expected result, I think it captures the structure of the list well enough, unless it would be better to add the output of "wordList" directly ?

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the input. Could you add the input that you would like to parse to the posted output?

Comment: The input is the content of the list, in the list definition. 
This would be to avoid resetting in each sublist the elems `sentenceType` and then within this sub-sub-list the elems `leBien` `leMal`. 
I imagine with Python it would be a list comprehension of some sorts.

Comment: could you post the expected input as well as the expected output? Since it is not clear what is what, in the question you mention the list is `Example expected output` while in the comment you post that this is the input.

Comment: I think the input would be the elems of the sub-sub list, e.g. `leBien = c("Bien", "le", "bonjour", "messieurs", "dames")`. 
But we don't need an input per say I think because we are defining a list. This is more on how to do the list definition as shown in `Example expected output`, but in a less verbose and more DRY way. Do I make sense ?